# this.setState is not a function xml request

Tags: react-native

How to pass the result to a state?

[Gist code](https://gist.github.com/gHashTag/25bb3c30d0e302db514b847d4c797135)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the value of 'this' is not the execution context of your component, so easiest way is to just write a new function, for example:

```
updateState(loading) {
   this.setState({loading})
}
```

and in your component constructor bind this, for example:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this)
}
```

and then use this.updateState({ db: events }) instead of this.setState

Comment: from your example I can not understand how to transfer `this.setState({ db: events })`
in 
`constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      db: [],
      loaded: false,
    }
  }`

Comment: well I was just using loading as an example, you can do something like:

updateState(data) {
   this.setState({...data})
}

then this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this)

then you can use it like this.updateState({db: events}) or this.updateState({loading: false})